# How to add header filters with autoColumns?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using [tabulator library](http://tabulator.info) to plot a table, with an option as **autoColumns:true** because columns are dynamic, that's working fine but, I also wanted to add header filter for each column, I have referred the documentation but I couldn't get the workaround. Below is the code,

```
init: function() {
      var _this = this;
      this.tabulator = new Tabulator("#example", {
        autoColumns:true,
        height:"500px",
        movableColumns: true,
        ajaxProgressiveLoad:"scroll",
        paginationSize:20,
        ajaxProgressiveLoadScrollMargin: 400,
        ajaxLoader: true,
        ajaxLoaderLoading: 'updating data',
        ajaxProgressiveLoadDelay: 200,
        ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){  
          return {last_page: _this.iTotalPage, data: response}; 
        }
      });
     this.setData(); 
},

setData: function() {
  this.tabulator.setData("/tableData", {searchValue: this.sSerachValue});
},
```

Is there any way to add a header filter, without selecting columns via (this.tabulator.getColumns()) and mapping each one to set filters function?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will meet your needs...
A suggestion anyway just by using the methods of this great library (which I recently discovered;)

```
    // here your starting code...

        this.setData();
        this.setHeaders();
    },
    setData: function() {
        this.tabulator.setData(tableData, {});
    },
    setHeaders: function() {
        var columns = this.tabulator.getColumnDefinitions();

        // basic code to adapt to your need
        columns.forEach(column => {
            column.headerFilter = "input";
        });

        this.tabulator.setColumns(columns);
    }
```

Or after the table builded from a button to trigger this

```
document.getElementById('setHeaders').onclick = function(e) {
    var columns = object.tabulator.getColumnDefinitions();

    columns.forEach(column => {
        column.headerFilter = "input";
    });

    object.tabulator.setColumns(columns);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done something similar to that. collected the labels as following, ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
   if(!_this.aColumns.length){
  _this.aColumns =  Object.keys(response.data[0]);            
   }         
   return response;
 }